# How can i bind parameter in zf2 tablegateway

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-db

How can i bind parameter in zend framework 2 using tablegateway, here is the code i am using

```
$adapter     =   $this->tableGateway->getAdapter(); 
$result      =   $adapter->query(
              "SELECT * "
             . "FROM TABLE "
             . "WHERE SOME_ID = $SOME "
             . "AND STATUS = 1 "          
);
$dataSource  =   $result->execute();        
$statement   =   $dataSource->getResource();
$result      =   $statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

please suggest me a secure query builder code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to bind parameter in Adapter not in TableGateway.
It can be done on many ways, but example that you post

```
$id  = 123;
$res = $adapter->query(
    "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE SOME_ID = ? AND STATUS = 1", [$id]
);
var_dump($res->current());
```

There is a second parameter in function **query()** which is

```
@param string|array|ParameterContainer $parametersOrQueryMode
```

So you can play little bit with this option(s)... also check function [Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::query();](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-db/blob/master/src/Adapter/Adapter.php#L157-L166)

---

Easier way is to use TableGateway:

```
$res = $this->tableGateway->select(['SOME_ID' => $id]);
$res->current(); // than you can use also toArray(), current(), etc.
```